# finding duplicated missing rows while comparing two dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, outer-join

I have to compare two dataframe (dmart and stg) which has same column names (a,b,c,d) -

'''

import pandas as pd

```
dmart = pd.DataFrame([[3,4,5,6],
                  ['oo','ew','sf','ef'],
                  [5,5,5,5],
                  [6,-6,5,9],
                  ['80', '90', '60', '70'],
                ['10','ba','ca','da'],
                 [1, 2, 3, 5]],columns={"a","b","c","d"})

stg = pd.DataFrame([['80', '90', '60', '70'],
                [5,5,5,5],
                [5,5,5,5],
                [6,6,5,6],
                ['1','ba','ca','da'],
                ['80', '90', '60', '70'],
                ['80', '90', '60', '70'],
                 [1, 2, 3, 5]],columns={"a","b","c","d"})
```

'''

I have to find the all missing rows(either it is duplicated)in dmart dataframe while comparing with stg dataframe

'''
Desired Output

```
[5,5,5,5],
[6,6,5,6],
['80','90','60',70'],
['1','ba','ca','da']
```

'''

I am using following approach -
(mycode) -

'''

```
merge = stg.merge(dmart,how='outer', left_on=['a','b','c','d'], 
              right_on=['a','b','c','d'], 
              suffixes=('_stg', '_dmart'), indicator=True)

df = merge.loc[merge['_merge'] == 'left_only']
```

'''

My Output results -

'''

```
df
a   d   c   b   _merge

6   6   5   6   left_only
1   ba  ca  da  left_only
```

'''

My approach is not taking the duplicate rows which are present in dmart only one time and present in stg multiple time , I want to include those rows in the output too ,

Could anyone help in this ?

Comment: You could add a `cumcount` per group to identify the number of replicates

Comment: `My approach is not taking the duplicate rows which are present in dmart only one time and present in stg multiple time` - are you sure? Because your code working correct. Is possible change data sample for see your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the duplicate rows with the drop_duplicate() function.

```
import pandas as pd
dmart = pd.DataFrame([[3,4,5,6],
              ['oo','ew','sf','ef'],
              [5,5,5,5],
              [6,-6,5,9],
              ['80', '90', '60', '70'],
            ['10','ba','ca','da'],
             [1, 2, 3, 5]],columns={"a","b","c","d"})

 stg = pd.DataFrame([['80', '90', '60', '70'],
            [5,5,5,5],
            [5,5,5,5],
            [6,6,5,6],
            ['1','ba','ca','da'],
            ['80', '90', '60', '70'],
            ['80', '90', '60', '70'],
             [1, 2, 3, 5]],columns={"a","b","c","d"})
df = pd.concat([dmart,stg])
df_dropped = drop_duplicates(ignore_index=True)
```

Output:-

```
    c   b   a    d 
 0  80  90  60  70 
 1  5   5   5   5 
 2  6   6   5   6 
 3  1   ba  ca  da
 4  1   2   3   5
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).